# how to complete id numbers generator code in python

Tags: python

Hi there I have a mission: to implement 10 ID numbers according to the exceptions and conditions in the code

i want that  the output will be

```
123456782
123456790
123456808
123456816
123456824
123456832
123456840
123456857
123456865
123456873
```

and somehow i  Can't reach the desired output, anyone can help?  :)

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_letters
digits = string.digits


class NumNotNineLong(Exception):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return "The number you provided is not nine digits long."

class NotNumber(Exception):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return "The input you provided is not an integer"

class IDIterator():

    increment = 1

    def __init__(self,_id):
        self._id = _id  

    def __iter__(self):
       return self 

    def __next__(self):

        while check_id_valid(str(self._id)[-9::]) == False:
            self._id *= 2
            self._id += IDIterator.increment
            IDIterator.increment += 1
        if check_id_valid(str(self._id)[-9::]):
            result = str(self._id)[-9::]
            self._id *= 2
            self._id += 1
            IDIterator.increment = 2
            return result



def check_id_valid(id_number):
    for letter in str(id_number):
        if letter not in string.digits:
            raise NotNumber
    numbers = [int(i) for i in str(id_number)]
    if len(numbers) != 9:
        raise NumNotNineLong
    set_numbers = []
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            set_numbers.append(numbers[i])
        else:
            set_numbers.append(numbers[i] * 2)
    true_numbers = []
    for num in set_numbers:
        if num > 9:
            temp = [int(i) for i in str(num)]
            true_numbers.append(sum(temp))
        else:
            true_numbers.append(num)
    if sum(true_numbers) % 10 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def main():
    result = IDIterator(123456780)
    for _ in range(10):
        print(result.__next__())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```